# Word stopped creating list elements on enter. How do you get it to do start again?

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a custom list in word.

When I'm done with one element in the list and I press enter to start a new line, I expect it to start with a new list element such that I can hit enter to come out a level or tab to indent a level.

However, Word simply gives me a new line and I have to manually turn the list back on and then hit enter until I'm back at the desired level.

I've tried going into the AutoFormat menu and Lists is checked off.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the style - it could be broken.

In word 2013 you would right click at the style shown in the Ribbon menu and click "modify".  Then make sure that "style for following paragraph" indeed is the list style of your choice and not the "Normal" style.